# HealthKit single workout location

Tags: swiftui, core-location, healthkit, applehealth

Workouts recorded by Apple Workouts app on Apple Watch assign a location to stationary workouts, which is displayed as a pin in the Apple Fitness app.

[image]

This does not seem to be a `HKWorkoutRoute` (displayed as a route heatmap in Apple Fitness), which is used for workouts that have moved (such as cycling or running), as trying to load the `HKWorkoutRoute` for this workout leads to an empty list.

It's not a workout metadata either (like weather and humidity are). The documentation from Apple only offers guidance on `HKWorkoutRoute`s and not this singular location property.

How is this single location added to workouts from Apple Workouts, how can I as a developer read the location to display a map with a pin in my app, and how can I as a developer assign a location to the workouts I am writing to Apple Health, to ensure the best interoperability with Apple Fitness and other apps reading my workout type?

Comment: @Magnas This question is about attaching a GPS location obtained through core-location to a HealthKit workout, not how to get a GPS location.

Comment: I guess you figured it out, but you can add anything to metadata, like a latitude and a longitude, and maybe a string with an actual address. But sadly there is still not a way to access the location stored by Apple's Fitness app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is stored/used by Workout/Fitness apps and isn't available as API. You can try storing a workout route with a single location to get effectively the same behaviour for your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, this does not make my app interoperable with Fitness and other apps. I wish there was a standard for storing the workout location that both Apple and developers adhere to. Worth opening a Feedback?

Comment: Yes, please file a feedback.

How does it look if you do save a workout route with just one location? It may look different from what Fitness shows for Watch workouts but is it not feasible?

Comment: This is a great use case for HealthKit metadata fields. You could use this instead of a HKWorkoutRoute with a single coordinate for your own implementation. It would be nice if Apple provided a global metadata key to standardize this and expose their hidden location value, similar to `HKMetadataKeyTimeZone` etc.